# An NA error in my Gibbs sampler for mixture model

Tags: r

I am working on a Gibbs sampler and my code is as follows. The idea is (1)sample `pi` first (2) sample `delta` (3) sample `beta`.

```
  library(foreign)
   cognitive `=read.dta("http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/arm/examples/child.iq/kidiq.dta")`
 summary(cognitive)
 cognitive$mom_work = as.numeric(cognitive$mom_work > 1)
 cognitive$mom_hs = as.numeric(cognitive$mom_hs > 0)

# Modify column names of the data set
colnames(cognitive) = c("kid_score", "hs", "IQ", "work", "age")

 x<-cbind(cognitive$hs, cognitive$IQ, cognitive$work, cognitive$age)
 y<-cognitive$kid_score
 lmmodel<-lm(y~x-1, data=cognitive)
  NSim=3000 #iteration 
 Betahat=solve(t(x)%*%x)%*%t(x)%*%y
```

Error in if (delta[ite, j] == 1) rnorm(1, mu1, sigma1) else rnorm(1, mu0,  :
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In rbinom(1, 1, prob = (p1/(p0 + p1))) : NAs produced
2: In rbinom(1, 1, prob = (p1/(p0 + p1))) : NAs produced

Comment: where's your `rbern()` coming from - which package?

Comment: @VasilyA It is Bernoulli in R.

Comment: there's no package with such name AFAIK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

error is caused by the line `prob=(pi[ite]*exp(-beta[ite-1,j]^2/(2*10^2)))/(((1-pi[ite])*10^3)*exp(-beta[ite-1,j]^2/(2*10^(-4)))+pi[ite-1]*exp(-beta[ite-1,j]^2/(2*10^2)))`: at some iteration `prob` becomes greater than 1, so `rbern()` returns `NA`. Check your formula.

UPD. For debugging, add the following before your `delta[ite,j]=rbern(...` line:

```
prob_full <- (pi[ite]*exp(-beta[ite-1,j]^2/(2*10^2)))/(((1-pi[ite])*10^3)*exp(-beta[ite-1,j]^2/(2*10^(-4)))+pi[ite-1]*exp(-beta[ite-1,j]^2/(2*10^2)));
cat('\n',ite,j,prob_full)
```

Comment: I check my `rbern()` is right. Where other errors do you think?

Comment: In my code, the values of `beta` are +inf or -inf...

Comment: the problem is in the probability (`prob` parameter) passed to `rbern()` function: at some iteration, it becomes >1, so obviously the function can't work and returns `NA`

Comment: But I fixed the parameters of `beta`, the algorithm works.. This seems to show that the code of `delta` and `pi` is right?

Comment: well I'm not sure what you fixed; I have just checked again and the problem is still there. See the update in my answer for debugging lines.

Comment: I fixed the `beta` with hat{beta}.

Comment: with the code you currently show in the question, the problem is still there.

Comment: But in the formula, this is a ratio of  $A/(A+B)$. Why this could be greater than 1?

Comment: it does not look like `A/(A+B)`. Your numerator is `pi[ite]*exp(-beta[ite-1,j]^2/200)` and denominator is `((1-pi[ite])*1000)*exp(-beta[ite-1,j]^2/(2e-4))+pi[ite-1]*exp(-beta[ite-1,j]^2/200)`

Comment: Oh... Sorry, that should be `pi[ite]*exp(-beta[ite-1,j]^2/200)` which same as the numerator.

Comment: update the code in your question to show what it should be

Comment: Yes, I edited it. Although it runs successfully the trace plot is not good.

Comment: Then try to explain in your question, what means "not good" for you. It might be that the problem is not in R but in the algorithm. Would be helpful if you could provide a source of the formulas that you use. Alternatively, you can try posting at [Stats SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: P.S. consider simplifying your notation, for example use `200` instead of `(2*10^2)`, or `2e-4` instead of `(2*10^(-4))` etc. - it will make it easier to read.

Comment: Please see my latest version.

Comment: again, this becomes not R question but stats question. We don't know the source of your formulas so it's hard to tell what is wrong.

Comment: I added the full conditions of `beta`. Do you think my code is right for this part? Why I cannot change the index for `ite` in my `out`..

Comment: It seems my code is wrong in these 4 times for loop...